# How to improve accuracy of transcripts from google cloud speech API

Tags: webrtc, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am working on a project where I need to do a search in my website using Speech to text. I am using google cloud speech API synchronous REST API.
I am obtaining the audio from the browser with the help of WebRTC getUserMedia() library.

My current configuration for recording the audio is:
Linear 16, 16 bit mono channel, 48KHz.

I have also added relevant phrase hints: Acronyms, frequent words etc.

The issue I am facing is that, the accuracy in Google Demo is far better than the results I am getting in my application. 
Here : https://cloud.google.com/speech/

Comment: Could you share some examples of what was recognized and what was supposed to be recognized? (Ideally including the audio).

Comment: If you can do so, try to set the language code for the speaker. A language code of EN-US for a British speaker returns considerably worse results than if the language code is set to EN-GB.

Comment: @FraukeNonnenmacher We have set the locale to EN-US and have been testing with the US English speakers.